# How to omit the Elasticsearch metadata?

Tags: elasticsearch, metadata

Is there a way to remove two hits and the _source attribute from the JSON attribute. I know for this approach: filter_path=hits.hits._source that accomplish almost the thing.

Let say I have thi response:

```
{
    "took" : 3,
    .....

    "hits" : {
        ......
        "hits" : [
            ....
            "_source" : {
                "name" : "test name",
                "age" : 20
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I want to get the response like this:

```
[
    {
        "name:" "test name",
        "age" : 20
    }
]
```

Comment: Please add more details.

Comment: I don't believe you can turn off the metadata but you can control what is returned within the source for each doc by using _source: ["name", "age"] as a top level clause in the query

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the **_source** by disabling it before indexing:

```
PUT tweets
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
     "_source": {
       "enabled": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After indexing when you'll search the index, it will not have the **_source**.

```
GET tweets/_search
```

will return:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "tweets",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1
  }
]
```

I am not sure why you wan't to omit the hits? Let me know then I'll update the answer.

Even you can omit the **_source** using:

```
GET twitter/_search
{
  "_source": "null"
}
```

will return:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "tweets",
    "_type": "doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {}
  }
]
```

**Note:** The data which is returned from Elasticsearch is in JSON format, if your application don't want some of the fields from that JSON, then you can omit them while serializing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for updating the question, as far as I am aware we can't do that in elasticsearch, a possible solution is to do that in your application while serializing the data returned. Even using **filter_path** you will get the same hierarchy. If you wish to change that hierarchy you will have to do that in your application.